# What are some good data augmentation techniques for document images?

Tags: python, deep-learning, data-augmentation

I have 1000 resume in png format and I am implementing MaskRcnn for object detection. What data augmentation techniques can I use to improve the mask Rcnn performance?

Comment: It would be useful to know what you are trying to segment?

Comment: Fields like name, skills, education etc.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think MaskRCNN or other semantic segmentation or object detection tools are appropriate for this task. Look into OCR libraries such as [Tesseract](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract).